# MYSQL not recognizing some special characters

Tags: mysql, collation

Why won't mysql recognize é and a lot more characters including em dash (—) ?? This is driving me nuts. i keep getting such errors like `Incorrect string value: '\xE9' for column` 
I am using mysql 5.5.6 , my tables are innodb and using collation utf8-default collation.
I don't know if this is important but I am doing bulk insert from a csv file which contains special characters and my fields are of type TEXT

Comment: Is it possible that you have some escaping issues in your csv file? Or is it from a trusted source.

Comment: Just tested `é` on utf8-default innodb table. Works when inserted into a TEXT field. Could be some other non-standard character from your CSV triggering this error.

Comment: Its me who is uploading from the backend. Not a user so definitely I am a trusted source.

Comment: You should also check the encoding type of your database connection.

Comment: OK. I have tested it directly and it is working. Could the mysql api using php be the cause? Should I use mysqli or is there something I have to do in PHP. I am using a php script to run the bulk insert

Comment: I have run the sql query directly from mysql i.e no PHP script. I still get the same error!!

Comment: The character encoding of your .CSV file could be wrong. Just resave the file in your editor and make sure it is not the encoding of the file. I have had this issue with my editor saving files as UTF-16.

Comment: Hey there Richard!! Please put your comment as an answer coz you are absolutely right. I was using excel 2010 to generate my CSV file but after reading your comment, I opened the CSv in notepad, saved it using the encoding as UTF-8, default is ANSI. tried to import it and it worked. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure the CSV file is in UTF8 and not the default ANSI. To do this open the csv file in notepad and using the save as option, ensure the encoding is in UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to `SELECT ... WHERE table_col LIKE "%–%"` (long dash) turned out it wasn't working because my .php file which was sending the query wasn't in UTF8 but instead in ANSI! Converting it to UTF8 did the trick!!

Comment: For me I discovered it was because the csv file was in ANSI and not UTF8

Answer (score 1):

It's probably down to your PHP MySQL client's connection settings. [Rob Allen's post](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/) can probably sort you out.

Rather than using a `SET NAMES utf8` query, which the PHP docs explicitly warns against, there is a [built-in function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) to do this for you in the mysqli extension: `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');`.

An alternative explanation for bad characters if you're already doing this is that MySQL's `utf8` charset isn't actually proper `UTF-8`... It only supports up to 3-byte characters and there are some increasingly common ones that use 4, specifically Emojis. Fortunately MySQL has a fix for this as of version 5.5.3: use the `utf8mb4` charset instead.

On a related note, the sort order in the default utf8 charset (with the `utf8_general_ci` collation) has a number of problems that may affect you in, for example, German. The fix here is to use the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, which provides a more accurate, though slightly slower collation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like one I have dealt with in the past, and I concur with Synchro that the client connection settings may be where you need to look. You probably need to specify UTF8 character set when starting the connection.

I use PDO, and initiate the connection with this:

```
$this->dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->user, $this->pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Before I started using PDO, I used this:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html